# Is there an existing Java class to convert data stored little-endian to integers by offset and length?

Tags: java, converters, endianness

I have a data file that is made up of various fields in little-endian order. I know what the offset and length are for each of the various fields. Is there an existing Java class that will convert by offset and length to an integer? For example: 17 00 00 00 53 43 43 41 11 00 00 00 AA 35 00 00. Bytes 1 thru 4 (17 00 00 00) is 0x00000017.

Comment: It's a file of bytes. There aren't spaces between the bytes (that 17 00 00 00 is really 17000000). What I was hoping for is a method that would return an integer if I passed it the input, offset and length.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If your file is a file of raw bytes you can use [`ByteBuffer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) to read the file in little endian mode, and then use [`asIntBuffer()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#asIntBuffer()) to read out the `int`s through an [`IntBuffer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/IntBuffer.html). If you need to navigate the file, you can use [`srcChan.position(targetPosition);`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#position()) to skip to your next "field".

```
try (RandomAccessFile srcFile = new RandomAccessFile("data/data.bin", "r");
     FileChannel srcChan = srcFile.getChannel();) 
{
    //    Careful with these casts if you have large files - channel size is a long
    ByteBuffer ib = ByteBuffer.allocate((int)srcChan.size());
    ib.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
    srcChan.read(ib);
    IntBuffer fb = ((ByteBuffer)ib.rewind()).asIntBuffer();
    while (fb.hasRemaining())
        System.out.println(fb.get());
}
```

Output:

```
23
1094927187
17
13738
```

If however you have a text file with a series of space delimited hex strings (the file format is unclear from your question) you'll have to add a bit of trickery to read that in, but once it is in you can use `ByteBuffer` in little-endian mode to read out the integers again.

The general process would be:

1. `inputString.split(" ")`
2. convert each element of that `String` array into a `byte[]`
3. use `ByteBuffer.wrap` to wrap the resulting `byte[]` and walk through the `int`s

It probably (not compile time tested) looks something like the below (which doesn't use an `IntBuffer`, just to show an alternative method):

```java
String input = "17 00 00 00 53 43 43 41 11 00 00 00 AA 35 00 00";
String[] source = input.split(" ");
byte[] sourceBytes = new byte[source.length];
for (int i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {
    sourceBytes[i] = (byte)Integer.parseInt(source[i], 16);
}
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(sourceBytes);
bb.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
while (bb.hasRemaining())
    System.out.println(bb.getInt());
```

The output is the same as for the first approach.

Comment: I don't mind the downvote, but would love some feedback

Comment: There is no evidence that the file consists of ASCII hex strings.

Comment: @EJP. Fair enough. There's no evidence that it's made of bytes, either, but you assume it is in your answer.

Comment: Yes there is. Otherwise 'bytes 1 through 4' wouldn't make sense.

Comment: @EJP. The OP has 1 experience point. A novice programmer may well refer to bytes in a string. Hence I have now asked the question to the OP directly so as to clarify the question.

Comment: 'Bytes 1 through 4' of this data as a space-delimited hex string would be '17 0'. And where on earth would he get such a file in the first place? You're inventing difficulties where they don't exist.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69933/discussion-between-andy-brown-and-ejp).

Comment: The input isn't really space-delimited, sorry for the confusion. ByteBuffer and srcChan.position(i) look like they'll do what I need done. Thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

Guava provides the [`LittleEndianDataInputStream`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/LittleEndianDataInputStream.html) class which can be used to retrieve values in little endian order.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with a `java.nio.IntBuffer` or `java.nio.ByteBuffer`, in association with a `java.nio.channels.FileChannel` to read the data.

Answer (score -1):

You should try to read it as it is. Get block of 4 bytes and treat them as integers. I'm sure JVM already treats numbers little endian (as far as I know, all Intel/amd are so).

Comment: The javadoc for `DataInput.readInt()` explicitly states that the data is read in big-endian order.